# ZXing Barcode Scanner , not returning FNC1 character for DataMatrix in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, zxing, barcode-scanner, gs1-datamatrix

I have been using **ZXing .Net** for scan **DataMatrix** (standard GS1) with Xamarin with following options. But still not getting ASCII value (FNC1).

```
private async void scanButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
        {
            PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() {                   
                ZXing.BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX
            }
        };
        options.AssumeGS1 = true;
        //Scanning part
        var barcode  = "";
        scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage(options);

        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Navigation.PopAsync();
                barcode = result.Text;
            });
        };

        await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
    }
```

Why i can't see ASCII value (FNC1) ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you show your "scanPage"? I expected to see Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage) somewhere in your code...Can you reach the code in your last lines in the debugger? If yes, what do you get in result.Text?

Comment: @Grisha , Yes I can reach to the last line. and if I copy return value in NotePad++ , I can see FNC character "GS" But how can I make it visible?

Comment: When I copy this value (result.Text) into notepad++ , I could see hidden ASCII character. Then I copied that one and use as a variable to replace with any symbol using String Replace method.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your problem. FNC1 is invisible character by definition, you can't *see* it. In any case, it has nothing to do with zxing barcode scanner and/or xamarin - they read the value right as far as I understand.

Comment: @Grisha, Thanks for your support. Actually, it was coming but not visible. I saw only when copying the value in Notepad++.